# getkey() of the specific path in firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

can someone help me on how can I get the specific key in the firebase.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wi510.png) is my firebase. I want to access the specific key in my "Patient List" to store a new data inside of it. but I don't know how to do it.

this is the code on getting the path in firebase.

```
       rootNode = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    ref = rootNode.getReference().child("Doctor List").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("Patient List");

    ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            SearchBarHelperClass value = snapshot.getValue(SearchBarHelperClass.class);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: If you try to log the value of `value`, or of a particular property within `value`, is there something printed out in the logcat?

Answer (score 0):

> You can get any Node/Node's key using the getKey() method of Firebase.

> For example :

```
String getKey = childSnapshot.getKey();
Log.e("Value of key is : ", getKey)
```

> will log the value of the key in your Logcat.

> In your case, do this :

```
 ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
String getKey = snapshpt.getKey();
            SearchBarHelperClass value = snapshot.getValue(SearchBarHelperClass.class);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
```

> Try it out. For more details , [click here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#ordering-by-a-specified-child-key)